# PHP Operators - make string true if equals a range

Tags: php, operators

I have a decent grasp on Python which I thought would help me here but I guess I dont have the programmers mind set yet :)

I am tweaking an existing PHP script that does a check on a MSSQL Server. Our script runs a query and compares the result with an expected result. Here is part of the script:

```
    if ($query_result == $expected_result) {
```

I need to modify this so that if the query_result is within +1 or -1 of the expected_result, to return true. Maybe soemthing like this?:

```
    if ($query_result <=> $expected_result -+ 1) {
```

I can't figure out how to properly write this :P All help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (abs($query_result - $expected_result) <= 1) {
   ... they're within "1" of each other
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (($expected_result -1) <= $query_result <= ($expected_result + 1)) {

}
```

Comment: This is totally broken code. it won't even get through the parser.

Comment: The above code was actually my initial way to go about this. I knew there must be a better way so I created this post :)